# Is there any way to assign a task to a specific node with nomad?

Tags: nomad

I want to use Nomad in our project. But from the docs i could not get an answer, is there any proper way for assign a task to a specific node, ignoring scheduling. Is there such an opportunity? 
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`constraint` stanza](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/constraint.html):

> The constraint allows restricting the set of eligible nodes. Constraints may filter on attributes or client metadata. Additionally constraints may be specified at the job, group, or task levels for ultimate flexibility.

```
  constraint {
    attribute = "${meta.my_custom_value}"
    operator  = ">"
    value     = "3"
  }
```